# create map with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand what is this error and how to correct them. I want to create a function similar to this one:

```
map(lambda x: x**2, range(5))
```

my map function:

```
def map(fct, *liste):
  if len(liste) > 0: 
    for i in liste:
        yield (fct(i))
```

The exception appear if function call is:

```
map(lambda x: x**2, [])
```

error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the star before `liste`:

```
def map(fct, liste):
```

**Or**, instead of passing empty array, pass nothing:

```
map(lambda x: x**2)
```

Also, this condition looks unnecessary: `if len(liste) > 0:`. With this condition, in case of empty list `map` will return `None` instead of an empty generator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for my english, it's my second language.